# Why isn't this code updating the behavior of the add to cart button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I am using the following to try to, among some other things, update an add to cart button to show as out of stock when a combination of options lead to a variant that is out of stock.

The code is triggered when the dropdown menus change. The prices are updating as desired, so I know that part is working fine.

But I cannot understand why the 'else' at the end never seems to fire, even if the combination is not available.

```
function letsDoThis() {
        {% if product.options[0] %}var opt1 = document.getElementById('select-one').value;{% endif %}
        {% if product.options[1] %}var opt2 = document.getElementById('select-two').value;{% endif %}
        {% if product.options[2] %}var opt3 = document.getElementById('select-three').value;{% endif %}
        var id = '';
        {% for v in product.variants %}
        if(opt1=="{{ v.option1 }}"{% if product.options[1] %} && opt2=="{{ v.option2 }}"{% endif %}{% if product.options[2] %} && opt3=="{{ v.option3 }}"{% endif %}) {
                var id = {{ v.id }};
                var price = "{{ v.price | money }}";
            }
        {% endfor %}
        if(id!='') {
            document.getElementById('product-select').value = id;
            document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = price;
            document.getElementById('add').className += " enable-add";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('product-select').value = '';
            document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'Unavailable';
            document.getElementById('add').className += " disable-add";
        }

    }
```

The image below shows the portion of the page that relies on the above code:

[image: Section of the page that this impacts...]

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use Shopify's OptionSelectors to create the drop-downs, then either use Shopify's link option selectors or add custom code to the selectCallback to take advantage of things that have already been written for the platform?

For troubleshooting this code specifically, are you able to share a site where this code is active so that I could step through the code to see where it's whiffing? It could just be that there's a misspelled class name or ID somewhere.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I did end up using Shopify's OptionSelectors and got it working. The reason I was avoiding it was because it was conflicting with simpleselect.js, a plugin I was using to customise the styles of the drop downs. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in your code at `var id = {{ v.id }}` on line 8.

You may be missing a quotation. So it would now read: `var id = "{{ v.id }}"`

```
function letsDoThis() {
    {% if product.options[0] %}var opt1 = document.getElementById('select-one').value;{% endif %}
    {% if product.options[1] %}var opt2 = document.getElementById('select-two').value;{% endif %}
    {% if product.options[2] %}var opt3 = document.getElementById('select-three').value;{% endif %}
    var id = '';
    {% for v in product.variants %}
    if(opt1=="{{ v.option1 }}"{% if product.options[1] %} && opt2=="{{ v.option2 }}"{% endif %}{% if product.options[2] %} && opt3=="{{ v.option3 }}"{% endif %}) {
            var id = "{{ v.id }}";
            var price = "{{ v.price | money }}";
        }
    {% endfor %}
    if(id!='') {
        document.getElementById('product-select').value = id;
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = price;
        document.getElementById('add').className += " enable-add";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('product-select').value = '';
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'Unavailable';
        document.getElementById('add').className += " disable-add";
    }

}
```